# NoSuchMethodError while using Generic DAO

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, nosuchmethoderror, genericdao

I'm trying to use GenericDAO in a project :

```
public class GenericDao<T> {
    ApplicationContext ctx =
            new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringMongoConfig.class);
    MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");

    public void save(T t) {
        mongoOperation.save(t);
    }

    public void delete(final T t) {
        mongoOperation.remove(t);
    }
}
```

The child class NoteDAO extends GenericDao and there's no need to override save/delete methods. But when I'm trying to use them I get: 
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.dao.NoteDAO.save(Lcom/example/model/Note;)V`

Here is my NoteDAO, it's empty:

```
public class NoteDAO extends GenericDao<Note> {
    public static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(NoteDAO.class);
    public static int counter = 0;
}
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Why are you extending from GenericDaoImpl? Didn't you say that you where extending from GenericDao? How is GenericDaoImpl defined?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo (edited now). Problem is still actual.

Comment: Is GenericDao perhaps in some dependency that you are importing?

Comment: GenericDao is imported from the same package.

Comment: Usually such an error occurs when a the classpath contains a version of a dependency that does not have the specified methods. Is there perhaps any other GenericDao on your classpath?

Comment: @geoand, there is no other GenericDao in classpath. Also IDE tells me that I use exactly same method from GenericDAO (when I use noteDAO.save(new Note()) in another classes). I thought there only be a problem with generics...

Comment: I really can't see what the problem could be... Do you have the code available in github or something?

Comment: I have a private repo in bitbucket. I can share it if you've got an account there.

Comment: I do have an account, however I don't have the credentials for it... I will have to get back to you in a few hours with them

Comment: geoand, that would be great, thanx a lot.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your scenario and it worked fine for me, even without wrapping the DAO.  Maybe you could write a unit test which demonstrates the behaviour?  Alternatively, the answer might be quite simply to override the save() method in NoteDao and call super.save() in there, although that shouldn't really be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to the problem is to add a no-arg constructor to NoteDAO.

Comment: Ok, if you could please share your bitbucket repository I will have a closer look when I have the time. Thanks

Comment: if previous solution worked for me (When I wrap delete method inside persist(Note n) method and then call noteDao.persist(new Note())), why doesn't it work without wrapping? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your scenario and it worked for me... See if you have some kind of code:

```
package com.x.y;

public class GenericDAO<T> {

   public void save(T t) {
       System.out.println("Generic Save");
   }

   public void delete(final T t) {
      System.out.println("Generic Delete");
   }
}
```

---

```
package com.x.y;

public class NoteDAO extends GenericDAO<Note> {

   public void persist(){
      save(new Note());
   }

}
```

---

```
package com.x.y;

public class Client {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    NoteDAO nDao = new NoteDAO();
    nDao.save(new Note());   
   }
}
```

So, when I run Client it prints: "Generic Save".

Just trying to help you.

Comment: it really helps. Thanx. But is there a possibility to call this method without wrapping it in NoteDAO?

Comment: If you are talking about save method being called from the place other than NoteDAO then the answer is - we have to call it from some sub class of GenericDAO or we can call it from the instance of GenericDAO itself. I do not see other places from where we can call this save method.